# How to delete tuple as the salary less than the average?

Tags: mysql, sql, average, sql-delete

Delete all instructors whose salary is less than the average salary of instructors

if i use the MySQL below:

```
delete from instructor
where salary< (select avg (salary) from instructor);
```

If we use the SQL above, it will lead to a problem: as we delete tuples from deposit, the average salary changes

So How to implements this?

I have an idea that

1. First, compute avg salary and find all tuples to delete
2. Next, delete all tuples found above (without 
            recomputing avg or retesting the tuples)

but when i implements this:
it always shows error in the Workbench with MySQL

```
delete 
from (select*
    from instructor
    where salary < (select avg(salary) from instructor)) as A
```

Can anyone help me to solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store the average into a variable.

```
set @average = (...)  
delete from instructor where salary < @average
```

Or if you want it to be in a single query:

```
delete from instructor 
cross join (SELECT avg(salary) as average from instructor) t 
where salary < average;
```

Comment: @Rajesh yea was doing an inner join when I had the group by..forgot to remove it after I change to cross join

Comment: Thx~ It's a good idea to use the **set** in MySQL, by the way, what's the problem about my implementation? First I select all the tuple if the salary less than the average, and then delete all those tuple I selected

Comment: @jyuan by having that select query inside the where clause, it is executed every time as it loop thru all the rows. row1 < (select ...)? delete, row2 < (select ...)? delete ect